# Good way to collect programmatically generated test suites in nose or pytest

Tags: python, nose, pytest

Say I've got a test suite like this:

```
class SafeTests(unittest.TestCase):
    # snip 20 test functions

class BombTests(unittest.TestCase):
    # snip 10 different test cases
```

I am currently doing the following:

```
suite = unittest.TestSuite()
loader = unittest.TestLoader()
safetests = loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(SafeTests)
suite.addTests(safetests)

if TARGET != 'prod':
    unsafetests = loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(BombTests)
    suite.addTests(unsafetests)


unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

I have major problem, and one interesting point

- I would like to be using nose or py.test (doestn't really matter which)
- I have a large number of different applications that are exposing these test
  suites via entry points.

  I would like to be able to aggregate these custom tests across all installed
  applications so I can't *just* use a clever naming convention. I don't
  *particularly* care about these being exposed through entry points, but I
  **do** care about being able to run tests across applications in
  site-packages. (Without just importing... every module.)

I do *not* care about maintaining the current dependency on
`unittest.TestCase`, trashing that dependency is practically a goal.

---

**EDIT** This is to confirm that @Oleksiy's point about passing args to
`nose.run` does in fact work with some caveats.

Things that *do not* work:

- passing all the files that one wants to execute (which, *weird*)
- passing all the *modules* that one wants to execute. (This either executes
  nothing, the wrong thing, or too many things. Interesting case of 0, 1 or
  many, perhaps?)
- Passing in the modules *before* the directories: the directories have to come
  first, or else you will get duplicate tests.

This fragility is absurd, if you've got ideas for improving it I welcome
comments, or I set up
[a github repo with my
experiments trying to get this to work](https://github.com/quodlibetor/test-loading-experiment).

All that aside, The following works, including picking up multiple projects
installed into site-packages:

```
#!python
import importlib, os, sys
import nose

def runtests():
    modnames = []
    dirs = set()
    for modname in sys.argv[1:]:
        modnames.append(modname)

        mod = importlib.import_module(modname)
        fname = mod.__file__
        dirs.add(os.path.dirname(fname))

    modnames = list(dirs) + modnames

    nose.run(argv=modnames)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runtests()
```

which, if saved into a `runtests.py` file, does the right thing when run as:

```
runtests.py project.tests otherproject.tests
```

Comment: I got what you are doing to work. I also got it to work if I load `unittest.TestCase` modules with `M=importlib.import_module(modname)` do `suite=unittest.findTestCases(M)` on them, and then do `nose.run(suite=suite)`. However, any idea how to pass nose arguments? I tried `nose.run(suite=suite, argv=['--with-xunit'])` but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a mess: Nose pretty much exclusively uses the
`TestLoader.load_tests_from_names` function (it's the *only function* tested in
[`unit_tests/test_loader`](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/master/unit_tests/test_loader.py))
so since I wanted to actually load things from an arbitrary python object I
seemed to need to write my own figure out what kind of load function to use.

Then, in addition, to correctly get things to work like the `nosetests` script
I needed to import a large number of things. I'm not at all certain that this
is the best way to do things, not even kind of. But this is a stripped down
example (no error checking, less verbosity) that is working for me:

```
import sys
import types
import unittest

from nose.config import Config, all_config_files
from nose.core import run
from nose.loader import TestLoader
from nose.suite import ContextSuite
from nose.plugins.manager import PluginManager

from myapp import find_test_objects

def load_tests(config, obj):
    """Load tests from an object

    Requires an already configured nose.config.Config object.

    Returns a nose.suite.ContextSuite so that nose can actually give
    formatted output.
    """

    loader = TestLoader()
    kinds = [
        (unittest.TestCase, loader.loadTestsFromTestCase),
        (types.ModuleType, loader.loadTestsFromModule),
        (object, loader.loadTestsFromTestClass),
    ]
    tests = None
    for kind, load in kinds.items():
        if isinstance(obj, kind) or issubclass(obj, kind):
            log.debug("found tests for %s as %s", obj, kind)
            tests = load(obj)
            break

    suite = ContextSuite(tests=tests, context=obj, config=config)

def main():
    "Actually configure the nose config object and run the tests"
    config = Config(files=all_config_files(), plugins=PluginManager())
    config.configure(argv=sys.argv)

    tests = []
    for group in find_test_objects():
        tests.append(load_tests(config, group))

    run(suite=tests)
```

Answer (score 4):

For nose you can have both tests in place and select which one to run using [attribute](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html) plugin, which is great for selecting which tests to run. I would keep both tests and assign attributes to them:

```
from nose.plugins.attrib import attr

@attr("safe")
class SafeTests(unittest.TestCase):
    # snip 20 test functions

class BombTests(unittest.TestCase):
    # snip 10 different test cases
```

For you production code I would just call nose with `nosetests -a safe`, or setting `NOSE_ATTR=safe` in your os production test environment, or call run method on nose object to run it natively in python with `-a` command line options based on your `TARGET`:

```
import sys
import nose

if __name__ == '__main__':
    module_name = sys.modules[__name__].__file__
    argv = [sys.argv[0], module_name]
    if TARGET == 'prod':
        argv.append('-a slow')

    result = nose.run(argv=argv)
```

Finally, if for some reason your tests are not discovered you can explicitly mark them as test with `@istest` attribute (`from nose.tools import istest`)

Comment: thanks, the `@attr` flag is pretty good, and solves the lovingly-crafted part of my question, but I don't know how I would go about exposing all of my attrs to external applications?

Comment: can't you set environment variable from external app?

Comment: I guess what you're saying is explicitly pass in all the modules to `nose.run`? I don't *think* that that will work unless nose knows automatically how to load a test suite? Which it might.

Comment: fwiw I tried this and doing `nose.run($VIRTALENV_SITE_PACKAGES/package/tests.py)` (forgive the pseudo-pybash) does not work unless you run it from *within* `$VIRTUALENV_SITE_PACKAGES`. I guess I could `os.chdir` before I `nose.run` but that seems... gross.

Comment: if you specify the module through the argument (argv) example as shown above by setting `module_name=$VIRTALENV_SITE_PACKAGES/package/tests.py` it should work. The first argument is a module name, and not a file.

Comment: I've updated my question with a working implementation of what I want. I *think* that your code doesn't actually handle the difficult parts of what I want, and my answer is still way more stupid than I would like it to be, so I'm going to upvote you but leave the question open in case I find something better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your question is, "How do I get pytest to 'see' a test?", you'll need to prepend 'test_' to each test file and each test case (i.e. function).  Then, just pass the directories you want to search on the pytest command line and it will recursively search for files that match 'test_XXX.py', collect the 'test_XXX' functions from them and run them.

As for the docs, you can try starting [here.](http://pytest.org/latest/getting-started.html)

If you don't like the default pytest test collection method, you can customize it using the directions [here.](http://pytest.org/latest/example/pythoncollection.html)

Comment: No I know how to use py.test, and my tests have the correct names, I want to be able to tell pytest that "this collection of tests generated by a script". (I'm dynamically generating the test suite, so a naming the standard name-based test discovery doesn't work.)

Comment: @quodlibetor: So when you say you are 'dynamically generating the test suite', you are not writing them to files (a la 'a.example.com/test/test_XXX.py') but are generating them as Python objects?

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to change your code to generate a `py.test` "suite" (my definition) instead of a unittest suite (tech term), you may do so easily. Create a file called `conftest.py` like the following stub

```
import pytest

def pytest_collect_file(parent, path):
    if path.basename == "foo":
        return MyFile(path, parent)

class MyFile(pytest.File):
    def collect(self):
        myname="foo"
        yield MyItem(myname, self)
        yield MyItem(myname, self)

class MyItem(pytest.Item):
    SUCCEEDED=False
    def __init__(self, name, parent):
        super(MyItem, self).__init__(name, parent)

    def runtest(self):
        if not MyItem.SUCCEEDED:
            MyItem.SUCCEEDED = True
            print "good job, buddy"
            return
        else:
            print "you sucker, buddy"
            raise Exception()

    def repr_failure(self, excinfo):
        return ""
```

Where you will be generating/adding your code into your `MyFile` and `MyItem` classes (as opposed to the `unittest.TestSuite` and `unittest.TestCase`). I kept the naming convention of `MyFile` class that way, because it is intended to represent something that you read from a file, but of course you can basically decouple it (as I've done here). See [here](https://pytest.org/latest/example/nonpython.html) for an official example of that. The only limit is that in the way I've written this `foo` must exist as a file, but you can decouple that too, e.g. by using `conftest.py` or whatever other file name exist in your tree (and only once, otherwise everything will run for each files that matches -- and if you don't do the `if path.basename` test for every file that exists in your tree!!!)

You can run this from command line with

```
py.test -whatever -options
```

or programmactically from any code you with

```
import pytest
pytest.main("-whatever -options")
```

The nice thing with py.test is that you unlock many very powerful plugings such as [html report](https://github.com/davehunt/pytest-html)

Comment: See also https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1569 which has some related suggestions

Comment: Can you use `pytest.main()` to test a specific package that is installed without pointing to the directory with the source code? Trying to find the easiest way to implement `test` method with `pytest`, so you can type `import XXX; XXX.test()`, like in NumPy.